# Implement Continuous Build and Deployment in an Enterprise with multiple projects of similar structure?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am given a task to automate our build process with a Continuous Build & Deploy tool. We use Gradle for building our java applications. The projects that we develop fall into these 3 categories.

1. Standalones - Deployed to Unix boxes.
2. EARs  (Usually has an EJB and Web project) - Deployed on Weblogic

I would like to use Jenkins pipelines to build these projects. I have decided on the following flow for standalones and EARs.

CheckOut & Build -> UnitTest -> Assemble -> Publish to Nexus (as Snapshot) -> Copy properties for DEV -> Deploy to Dev

Manually Trigger next stage to Release to Testers

Get artifact from Nexus Snapshot Repo -> Publish to Release Repo -> Copy Properties for TEST env -> Deploy to TEST

Manually Trigger deployment to Production

Copy Properties for PROD env -> Deploy to PROD

Since most of the tasks for all projects are similar like versioning, publishing to repository, building properties for each environment, Deployment to Server, etc., I wanted to have common pipeline script/downstream jobs for these.

So each developer will write gradle code for just defining dependencies and building projects. All other stages are same for every application/project and changing deployment process on one should reflect on all the applications.

I was not able to figure out how I could achieve this.

Comment: As you are newbie, don't try to look at implementing like enterprise level. First with available resources and knowledge what you have try to achieve end to end flow and by that time you might get an idea how it is behaving. According to the learning what you got based on that then try to upgrade to advanced level.

Comment: I'd recommend do as much as you can (should be actually everything really) in Gradle. You can create a corporate Gradle plugin that is applied by your projects and does all the configuration like you want it. Then you are not tied to a specific build server. Btw. I'd recommend TeamCity as build server, much better than Jenkins in my opinion. ;-)

Comment: the jenkins core maintainers themselves also recommend putting as much build logic as you can in external scripts (like any CI tool people ought to recommend). so i agree with Vampire. i think a major of downside of teamcity is the lack of pipelines as code (where you instruct the CI tool what to do using a file in your app's source control, like a Jenkinsfile)?